# Easy way to spliting string to get exact data

Tags: c#, string, split

I need to get x1 y1 x2 y2 values from string which is;

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";
```

In long way I can get string data between brackets such as;

```
int startIndex = rawStr.IndexOf("(") + "(".Length;
int stopIndex = rawStr.IndexOf(")");
string values = rawStr.Substring(startIndex, stopIndex - startIndex);
```

And then with regex I will try to parse one by one to all integer values. However is there any easy way to grab x1, y1, x2, y2 from string ?

Comment: Do x1,y1,x2,y2 *always* appear in that order?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the following regex and combine the results into dictionary, which will provide you easy access to results:

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";

var regex = new Regex("(?<type>(x|y)\\d):\\s(?<val>\\d+)");

var result = regex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Groups["type"].Value, 
        x => int.Parse(x.Groups["val"].Value));
```

To get the required values you can use the following code:

```
var x1 = result["x1"];
var y1 = result["y1"];
var x2 = result["x2"];
var y2 = result["y2"];
```

And named groups of regex will provide some kind of readability of this.

Group `(?<type>(x|y)\\d)` : is a group with a name `type` which searching for single char `x` or `y` (`x|y`) followed by single digit (`\\d`)

Group `(?<val>\\d+)`: is a group with a name `val` which searching for one or more digits (`\\d+`)

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this with RegEx only

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";
string pattern = @"(?<=[xy]\d: )\d+";
int[] result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str,pattern) 
                                               .Cast<Match>()
                                               .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
                                               .ToArray();
```

Explaination:

- `(?<=)` positive lookbehind, your match has to start with that but it's not part of the match
- `[yx]` your match has to start with `x` or `y`
- `\d:` followed by one digit, `:` and one space
- `\d+` your match is at leas one digit

---

If you want to keep the reference between e.g. `x1` and `750` you can also parse your result into a `Dictionary<string,int>()`

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";
string pattern = @"[yx]\d: \d+";
Dictionary<string, int> result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Split(new string[]{": "},  StringSplitOptions.None))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to use **Regex**

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";
var keyValuePairs = str.Split('(', ')')[1] // get what inside of the parentheses
                .Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // split them into {key:value}
                .Select(part => part.Split(':'))
                .ToDictionary(split => split[0].Trim(), split => int.Parse(split[1].Trim()));
```

How to get x1:

```
var x1 = keyValuePairs["x1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to solve your problem without using regex or LINQ

```
string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)";
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var values = str.Split(new char[2] { '(', ')'})[1].Split(new char[2] {':',';'});
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i+=2)
{
    dict.Add(values[i],int.Parse(values[i+1].Trim()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bbox class in system, you can convert your string to json format and Deserialize it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string str = "Bbox(x1: 750; y1: 300; x2: 1100; y2: 600)".Replace("Bbox(", "{").Replace(")", "}").Replace(";", ",");

     Bbox box = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bbox>(str);
}

class Bbox
{
     public int x1;
     public int y1;
     public int x2;
     public int y2;
 }
```